# Jsoup POST request failure. HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to log in a website(https://dashboard.ngrok.com/user/login) using jsoup. I hadn't any problem with GET request, but when I try to do a POST request using credential I recive:

HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400

I tried to set a better header for the request, using the same parameters that I send when I connect making a POST request.

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url)
           .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
System.out.println("GET");

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
           .data("email", usr)
           .data("password", psw)
           .header("Host", "dashboard.ngrok.com")
           .header("Origin", "https://dashboard.ngrok.com")
           .referrer(url)
           .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
           .post();
```

I also tried this type of request:

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .data("email", usr, "password", psw)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(ngrok)
    .cookies(loginCookies)
    .get();
```

The Output says:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=https://dashboard.ngrok.com/user/login

Comment: You can try with REST API tester first like Postman.

Comment: You have to send another parameter, called `csrf_token`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483577/difficulties-using-jsoup-logging-into-page/37485873#37485873) (read also the comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [TDG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426328/tdg) advised me I added the csrf_token.
The result code is this:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .userAgent(USER_AGENT).execute();

    Document tok = loginForm.parse();
    Element e = tok.select("input[name=csrf_token]").first();
    String appToken = e.attr("value");
    System.out.println(appToken);
    Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("email", usr)
                .data("password", psw)
                .data("csrf_token", appToken)
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .header("Host", "dashboard.ngrok.com")
                .header("Origin", "https://dashboard.ngrok.com")
                .referrer(url)
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();
```

Thank you for the help.